# WP7: What is the easiest way to convert a group of textboxes from text to a number or decimal value?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, string-conversion

So I have users inputting numbers into multiple text boxes and I need to check that they are not null and convert them to decimal. Is there a simpler way to do this than a separate IF for each textbox?

```
if (txtBoxAuto1.Text != null)
{

    String varStrTxtBox1 = txtBoxAuto1.Text;
    decimal varTxtBox1 = Decimal.Parse(varStrTxtBox1);


}
```

I tried putting an "and" after the first textbox and it didn't seem to like it.

Comment: I realize I can take that comma out at the end of the parse line...

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with each text box value. Please provide more information.

Comment: If you are using databinding you can use a [value converter](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/15/so-what-s-a-silverlight-value-converter-anyway.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did such stuff, I added the Textboxes into a list to loop thought them.
Or if you have all Textboxes in a panel you can loop thought them just like

```
foreach(Control c in this.panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && c.Text != String.Empty)
            {
                decimal myValue = Convert.ToDecimal(c.Text);
            }
        }
```

Or did I miss the point?

Comment: Ah, so this will only loop through the textboxes I have in a panel and then stop. This is probably what I want. Easier to code.

Answer (score 1):

The logical AND in C# is &&.

```
if (txtBoxAuto1.Text != null && txtBoxAuto2.Text != null ...)
```

If all of the text boxes have to NOT be NULL, then just add the logical AND in the if statement condition. Otherwise, if some can be NULL and not others, you'll need a separate IF statement for each of the text boxes which can be NULL.

Comment: Very awesome!! that will save me a ton of time. I new there was a way, just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using WPF/Silverlight on WP7: it is probably best to follow the model-view-viewmodel ([MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)) pattern as with other WPF/Silverlight apps and use databinding.

I'd approach it with a viewmodel that exposes:

- an "external" (to the view) databound string property called `FirstNumberText` or whatever you want - this is the one that is bound to the textbox.
- an "internal" (to the rest of the app) number property `FirstNumber` that parses `FirstNumberText` on the fly and contains whatever other business logic is required - you'll call this when you want the actual `Decimal` number.

This also means that invalid entries won't cause databinding to fail, so you can trivially use the built in validation functionality of databinding (including handy [attributes](http://wildermuth.com/2009/09/28/How_Silverlight_3_Validation_Works)) to deliver a friendly error message to the user if the text entered is empty or is inappropriate in some other way (negative, too big/small, etc).

Since you're using MVVM instead of directly interacting with controls from the view, you can also radically change the interface without worrying as much about breaking logic (by removing/renaming controls).

Comment: Any particular reason you suggest exposing FirstNumberText instead of using a value converter?

Comment: It's a habit that I've gotten into because doing a databinding with both value conversion and validation has historically been difficult for a later developer to understand. You're right in that a value converter would be the best way to go, though, and wouldn't require two properties.